# If statement not working with NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, jailbreak, nsnumber, theos

I'm new to coding and can't find an accurate answer anywhere. I'm trying to make the NSNumber return false if the BOOL is true. Any help? Thanks

```
static BOOL someBOOL;

%hook  (class I want to hook)

-(void)sampleMethod:(NSNumber *)boolNumber
{
    if (!someBOOL) 
    {
        [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    } 
    else 
    {
        return %orig;
    }
}

%end
```

Comment: What does it mean by %hook ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to state this is a tweak for jailbreak, so %hook is used to hook into a class and use its methods

Comment: You're forgetting the `return`, also your method states `void` as a return value, not `NSNumber`

Comment: `someBOOL` is not given a value in the supplied code.

Comment: You may want to use `[yourNSNumberObject boolValue]`

Answer (score 0):

Init `someBOOL`:

```
static BOOL someBOOL = YES;
```

Then

```
if (!someBOOL) 
{
    return [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
} 
else 
{
    return %orig;
}
```

And to return replace `void` with `NSNumber` and remove excess parameter

```
-(NSNumber*)sampleMethod
```

To get returned value:

```
NSNumber *n = [self sampleMethod];
```

Comment: I did this and I got the error: "cannot initialize return object of type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') with an rvalue of type NSNumber *"

Comment: Where does  NSNumber *n = [self sampleMethod]; go?

Comment: NSNumber has a method called boolValue. Use it on the line that is causing this: "cannot initialize return object of type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') with an rvalue of type NSNumber *'. [https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsnumber_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/boolValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsnumber_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/boolValue)

Comment: @nicael Please use either `YES` or `NO` to initialize a `BOOL` variable. Also keep in mind that `someBool` will be initialized to `NO` by default.